# JOOMLA: How to get the names of parents in simple component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm developing my own component for Joomla but I'm beginner in PHP and don't know how to get the names of parents. I have the table #__records (for example):

```
id  name           parent
1   ChildName      2
2   ParentName1    0
3   ParentName2    0
```

and I have the field **name="parent" type="list"** at **admin.../models/forms/record.xml**. If I open the record "ChildName" at back-end for editing I see the drop-down list for choosing parent but it's empty. I need to get the names of parents i.e. "ParentName1, ParentName2" at this list. What do I need to write in **admin.../models/record.php** at function getItem() ?

Joomla 3.4

Answer (score 0):

try field type '[sql](https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type)' instead of list inside record.xml
or create custom filed inside edit.php